# Rails 3 Plugin - Active Record table_name_prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, plugins, prefix, tablename

Im having problem to use **table_name_prefix** on my projects. I have a main apllication in my project that have others applications as plugins, these plugins works like a subsystem from the main application.

To organize the tables on database of the subsystems I would like to use the **table_name_prefix** of the **ActiveRecord** Plugin.

If I put on **init.rb** of plugin the command **config.active_record.table_name_prefix = "per_"** the main application will not work because the ActiveRecord will try to find for "per_users" but the only thing I want is that only the Plugin on my main application use the prefix "per_".

I tried to create a rails folder at my plugin with the command above but the same problem occurs, all the application try to find for prefixed table name.

An alternative is use the **set_table_name** in the model of plugin, but its not good for me because Im developing subsystems as rails plugin and I dont want to change the models when put the subsystem at the main application.

Someone can help me?

Comment: What version of rails are you using?

Answer (score 3):

To have each plugin with own prefix, for Rails 3, try organize Your models inside plugin in namespace:

```
class Foo::Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
 ...
end

module Foo
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'foo_'
  end
end
```

This will works just inside the plugin without changing anything inside the main application.
Other approach is to use some main model and inherit it from others like that:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'foo_'
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
 ...
end
```

sometimes this approach is used to extend all models with extra features.

More information in Rails documentation [here](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.1.0/ActiveRecord/Base/table_name_prefix/class)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930418/ruby-on-rails-model-not-following-namespace-updated). I ran into the same problem, forgot my application's name (main module) had the same name as a namespace for my models.